# Ruby Mongodb / Mongoid merge grouped records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, aggregation-framework

Here is my table/collection "records" in the Mongodb
[image]

I need to get this array of data, grouped by unique value of field_1 and merged values from the fields (field_2, field_3, field_4)

```
[
  {field_1 => value_1, field_2 => value_2, field_3 => value_3, field_4 = value_4},
  {field_1 => value_N, field_2 => value_2, field_3 => value_3, field_4 = value_4}
]
```

I am using Ruby on Rails and mongoid, with mongoid I can do somthing like this

```
uniq_filed_values = db.records.distinct(:field_1)
merged_results = []
uniq_field_values.each do |value|
   merged_result = db.records.where("field_1" => value).map{|v| v.attributes}.inject(&:merge)
   merged_results << merged_result
end
```

I would like to know if there is any way to do the same thing within the database/Mongodb or mongoid without using so much ruby. I am looking for the possible solutions with Mongodb map/reduce or aggregation? Or maybe there is a better solution for my sample?

P.S Please note - there are more than 1 000 000 records in this table/collection.

Thanks for helping!